# JBoss AS 4.x class loading in case of multiple EARs

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ehcache, ear, second-level-cache

I have the following scenario. I have two EARs A and B. Each of these EARs have a common-beans.jar which is packaged with in the EAR. The common-beans.jar contains all the entity beans (Hibernate ORM) of the app. Now, I want to use hibernate's second level cache with Ehcache, when I use the standard configuration which is:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

I see that each of my applications A and B have their own version of cache, and updates on one is not reflected on the other, where as I ideally wanted that to be referencing the same cache instance. I have packaged the eh-cache jar, hibernatejar, common-beans.jar and all others within the EAR, since I want it to be hot-deployable.

Can anyone help me with the above? Essentially, what I am looking at is a shared cache across multiple EARs.
JAR version - Hibernate version is - 3.0 ehcache version is 2.6
I am trying it on JBOSS 4.1AS

Comment: Hibernate version is -  3.0 ehcache version is 2.6

Comment: Add that to the question pls. So I assume it's JBoss AS 4.1 or so?